# Truncate Unity interceptor IParameterCollection

Tags: c#, unity-container, interceptor

For logging purposes I use a unity interceptor. I want to get all arguments of the called method (and some more info that is not relevant to this question). These can be find in IMethodInvocation.Arguments, This argumens property is of type IParameterCollection.

The problem is, that when a argument is a list with for example, 16000 string values, we see performance issues.

Is there any way to pick a maximum of for example, 10 items in a argument?

The Unity version I use is: 2.0.0.